# Is it possible to boot in to other OS after one boot failure

Tags: windows, boot, multi-boot, bootloader

I have dual boot system, windows 7 and windows 10. i was wondering if for some reason my system fails to boot in to windows 10 my system automatically boots in to other windows in this case windows 7 ?

i have been looking at bcdedit / bcdboot to find such an option but seems like these is no such option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time playing with bcdedit found the answer in recoverysequence. posting here if anybody is interested.

bcdedit /set {current GUID} recoverysequence {other OS GUID}

bcdedit /set {current} recoveryenabled Yes

{current} is you current GUID for default boot. works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such option.

If the system could recover from a failure, then it would simply recover.  There's no reason for it to recover by deciding to start an older operating system.

Once the system firmware (BIOS/(U)EFI) passes control to an operating system, that control is passed.  The firmware doesn't retain the right to judge, "Hmm, I think Windows 10 didn't boot up as well as it normally does.  I will snag control back and pass control onto Windows 7."

I'm not saying that such things would be impossible, but they didn't seem sensibly desirable enough for the system designers to actually design systems that way.  It would require a level of complexity that not many people would want the system designers to invest in.  Instead, it would be better if the complexity were added to the operating system so that it could just recover from minor errors and still boot successfully.